# How to retrieve gif asset from firebase storage ? Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I try to retrieve the gif asset from firebase storage but I have a problem, that **gif turns into an image**.

Here my onCreate function :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice)

    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("gif/step1.gif")
    val localFile = File.createTempFile("tempGif", "gif")
    storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {

        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.absolutePath)
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to retrieve the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    init()
    dataSet()
    interaction()
}
```

I am using GifImageView library, screenshot for my layout XML below :
[image]

Here I share the app output screenshot :
[image]

Any help and solution, I am very grateful...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I looked on your usage it's quite straightforward to put things together

```
val gifFromPath =  GifDrawable( localFile.absolutePath )
img.setImageDrawable(gifFromPath)
```

See https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable